# Сильно тормозит Visual Studio(2017)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

При написании кода студия начинает сильно тормозить (1-2) секунды, потом отлагивает, и так все время.Проблема появилась пару дней назад.Обновлена до последней версии.Такая же проблема и в visual studio 2010 года, но нет в visual C#.Переходить на эти старые версии не вариант.Заранее буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Если HDD, то дефрагментировать, и лучше не родной утилитой, или поставить SDD, отключить антивирус, удалить ReSharer, помониторить загруженность системы во время лагов, особенно по дискам, как вариант через resmon.exe или Process Explorer

Comment: Я бы посоветовал не решарпер удалять если таков стоит, а отключить красивости, и стандартный IntelliSence, заменив его на решарпер. А еще на хабре есть статьи про оптимизацию скорости работы MVS. Отключите канал новостей.

Comment: @Birdy +1 что  не надо отключать решарпер. А ссылки на статьи почему не привели? Было бы неплохо.

Comment: 1) [Часть 1](https://habrahabr.ru/post/117663/)

2) [Часть 2](https://habrahabr.ru/post/117670/)

3) [Часть 3](https://habrahabr.ru/post/117675/)

Comment: Та же беда. Мне кажется проблема в том, что студия "озаботилась" расходом памяти. Когда в ней активно работаешь - жрет за 300 мегов, а стоит чуть-чуть отвлечься, как расходуемая память падает до 50. Возвращаешься к работе и ждешь пока она наберет прежние 300.

Answer (score 3):

Всё зависит от характеристик вашего железа, а именно: производительности процессора, частоты и количества оперативной памяти, скорости работы жёсткого диска / твердотельного накопителя. Также, проверьте, не заполнен ли диск C, а также диск установки Visual Studio.

Если честно - студия всегда лагает, даже на самом сильном железе. Вопрос в том, насколько тяжело это дело происходит и конечно-же частота таких "лагов" - в зависимости от железа это происходит с определённой периодичностью.

По своему опыту скажу, что переустановка зачастую помогает (возможно лаги спровоцированы ошибками в ПО).

Также, плагин ReSharper ужесточает лаги из-за своей "тяжести". Если он у вас установлен - попробуйте отключить его.

Comment: Отключать решарпер -- это плохая рекомендация, он даёт очень много полезных вещей.

Comment: @A K: Сам решарпером пользуюсь, великолепная штука, но как говорится "Нет фич без багов". После его инсталляции Visual Studio может работать намного медленнее.

Comment: @AK если бы он при этом не лагал...